# Wpf MVVM выделить ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, listview, mvvm

Пишу Wpf MVVM приложение, в рантайме заполняю элемент `ListView` строками, после заполнения я могу только кликать по элементам, но не могу выделять текст внутри и соответственно его копировать.
Как реализовать возможность конечного пользователя выделять элементы `ListView` и копировать текст?

Comment: Переопределите вид элемента, засунув туда TextBox например...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BlaBlaBla}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Background="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    Text="{Binding Path=.,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я уже так и сделал, но спасибо большое за ответ)